# Redux reducer affecting different reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

Im having trouble with react redux reducers affecting the wrong reducers for no apparent reason to me.
The reducers are there to open and close modals via react style. When the successModal actions are called, for some reason they affect the loginModal reducer, but not vice versa. Hopefully you guys can help me :)

Actions

```
export const loginModalAppear = () => {


return {
    type: 'LOGIN_MODAL_APPEAR',
  };
};

export const loginModalDisappear = () => {
  return {
    type: 'LOGIN_MODAL_DISAPPEAR',
  };
};

export const successModalAppear = () => {
  return {
    type: 'SUCCESS_MODAL_APPEAR',
  };
};

export const successModalDisappear = () => {
  return {
    type: 'SUCCESS_MODAL_DISAPPEAR',
  };
};
```

Success modal reducer

```
const successModalReducer = (state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'}, action) => {


switch (action) {
  case 'SUCCESS_MODAL_APPEAR':
    return state = {opacity: 1, pointerEvents: 'all'};
  case 'SUCCESS_MODAL_DISAPPEAR':
    return state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'};
  default:
    return state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'};
  }
};

export default successModalReducer;
```

Login modal reducer

```
const loginModalReducer = (state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'LOGIN_MODAL_APPEAR':
    return state = {opacity: 1, pointerEvents: 'all'};
  case 'LOGIN_MODAL_DISSAPEAR':
    return state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'};
  default:
    return state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'};
  };
};

export default loginModalReducer;
```

if you need any other code let me know :)

Comment: Code is formatted stranglely with blank lines. Apolgies

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "affected"? All reducers get your action, so if reducer didn't catch action, default case will be executed, and in default you set new value.

Comment: `switch (action)` -> `switch (action.type)` in "Success modal reducer". Also in the default case you should return the current state not the default state.

Answer (score 0):

In redux, every action is always forwarded to every reducer. Since your reducer does a `default` case that returns something potentially different than the state before, every of those "other actions" will trigger that `default` case.

So your reducer should really look like

```js
const loginModalReducer = (state = {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'LOGIN_MODAL_APPEAR':
    return {opacity: 1, pointerEvents: 'all'};
  case 'LOGIN_MODAL_DISSAPEAR':
    return {opacity: 0, pointerEvents: 'none'};
  default:
    return state
  };
};
```

(also note that assigning to the state variable does nothing, so I removed that)

Generally, you are learning a very outdated style of redux here, so I guess you are following an outdated tutorial. Modern redux looks very different. Please follow the official tutorials over at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index to learn modern redux (which will make 75% of your code obsolete).

Comment: Thank you, this worked :) I see, I'll have a look at that now. Appreciated a lot :)